# How to Retrieve name of current Windows User (AD or local) using Python?

Tags: python, active-directory

How can I retrieve the name of the currently logged in user, using a python script? The function should work regardless of whether it is a domain/ad user or a local user.

Comment: you wanna check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/611007 not sure about domain

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
import os;
print os.environ.get( "USERNAME" )
```

That should do the job.

Comment: @Marcel Levy -  i know its pretty old, but for the rest who stumble on this... os.environ is returning a dictionary. get("USERNAME") is looking the key in the dict.

Answer (score 5):

as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/611007 by [Konstantin Tenzin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102243/konstantin-tenzin)

> Look at [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module
>
> ```
> import getpass
> getpass.getuser()
> ```
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows
>
> Note "*this function looks at the values of various environment
>   variables to determine the user name. Therefore, this function should
>   not be relied on for access control purposes (or possibly any other
>   purpose, since it allows any user to impersonate any other).*"

at least, definitely preferable over `getenv`.

Answer (score 2):

```
win32api.GetUserName()

win32api.GetUserNameEx(...)
```

See:
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Python, but for windows the underlying api is [GetUserNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724435(VS.85).aspx), I assume you can call that in Python if os.environ.get( "USERNAME" ) doesn't tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty old question but to refresh the answer to the original question "How can I retrieve the name of the currently logged in user, using a python script?" use:

```
import os
print (os.getlogin())
```

Per Python documentation: getlogin - Return the name of the user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process.

Comment: Since we're all responding to old items anyways, the original question was how to get the **Windows** User login name - `os.getlogin()` is not available in Windows versions of Python.

Comment: Question mentioned Windows.