# Is there a portable way to get the current username in Python?

Tags: python, portability

What is a portable way (e.g. for Linux and Windows) to get the current user's username? Something similar to `os.getuid()` would be nice:

```
>>> os.getuid()
42

# Does not currently exist in Python
>>> os.getusername()
'slartibartfast'
```

The [`pwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html) module works for Unix only. Some people suggest that getting the username under Windows can be complicated in certain circumstances (e.g., running as a Windows service).

Comment: `import pwd, os; print pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_gecos` or `import pwd, os; print pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name`

Comment: "username" is not even a portable _concept_. Consider microPython -- if you're running directly on hardware there's no such thing.

Answer (score 1075, accepted):

Look at [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module

```
import getpass
getpass.getuser()
'kostya'
```

Availability: Unix, Windows

---

p.s. Per comment below "*this function looks at the values of various environment variables to determine the user name. Therefore, this function should not be relied on for access control purposes (or possibly any other purpose, since it allows any user to impersonate any other).*"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with getpass.getuser(), since does not claim to authenticate the user. The purpose of the function is to determine who the user is claiming to be without asking the user directly.

Comment: That does not work if you've done a su.
$ echo $USER
hithwen
$ su julia
Password:
$ echo $USER
julia
$ python
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'hithwen'

Comment: @GregHewgill raises a very good point, but indeed, finding out the username in a simple unauthenticated way like this does have some applications. My current use-case: tagging some shared testing resources with a username for easy cleanup later. (So it's easier to figure out whose mess is whose.)

Comment: @hithwen What version are you using?  In 2.7.4 your example works as expected for me.

Comment: And I agree with @GregHewgill for the access control purposes, but completely disagree with 'any other purpose' - that's like saying "Don't use $USER in a shell script".  Great point about access control but there are *plenty* of other uses that don't involve auth.

Comment: @hithwen That's working as intended. It depends on which arguments you give to `su`. Perhaps you wanted to use `su - julia`.

Comment: Doesn't work with sudo!  To get the sudo user, I ended up using this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137176/112190

Comment: Works on OSX too, at least as of Sept. 2016!

Comment: what if we have several users?

Comment: Note that the `USER` variable isn't always set, e.g. in a container. However, I tested `getuser()` in Python 3.6.3 and 2.7.11 with `USER` unset, and it still works.

Comment: Make sure to `SET USERNAME=vmuser` if you're running a Windows VM provided by Microsoft because otherwise this won't work

Comment: @Dr.YounesHenni What do you mean? There is always only one user active at any time.

Comment: @phyatt It works as intended. The user *is* root when you're running with sudo. If you want to get the user who called sudo, that's a different question.

Comment: getpass is part of the standard library.

Comment: plus 1 = 1000. Congrats :)

Comment: This does not work reliably. Why? Because it will just read USER, USERNAME, LNAME, LOGUSER environment variables (check the source). Each of these can be overriden but there is still a "real" current user (e.g by invoking a subprocess running id -un)

Comment: E.g. run `LOGNAME=dumb python -c "import getpass;print(getpass.getuser())"`

Answer (score 173):

Combine `os.getuid()` with `pwd.getpwuid()`:

```
import os
import pwd

def get_username():
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
```

See [`pwd`](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html) docs for more details.

Comment: Alternatively (slightly nicer to read): `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name`.

Comment: What does it do on Windows? Perhaps one could try this, and if it fails, fall back to the crappy 'getpass/env var' methods.

Comment: This is the correct way if you need to get the username both with and without logging in.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: `ImportError: No module named pwd`

Comment: This method is on unix-like systems **much** superior to Konstantin Tenzin's answer, because it  handles the `sudo` case correctly. (I am aware the OP didn';t ask for unix-like ssytems.)

Comment: @halloleo When running with sudo, the expected behavior *is* for it to return `root`. That is by design and the other answers are not "wrong". You are simply asking for the answer to a different question.

Comment: Wrong answer -- this is NOT portable to Windows.

Answer (score 131):

You can also use:

```
os.getlogin()
```

Comment: On linux, getlogin() returns the name of the "user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process."  It therefore fails when there is no controlling terminal, e.g., in a mod_python application.

Comment: If you used su, then this won't return the current user, but the originally logged in user.

Comment: does work on windows...Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os; os.getlogin()
'jrb'

Comment: It's only available on Windows for Python 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for this. The login user is not exactly what the poster asked for but it is what I was looking for.

Comment: On linux, `os.path.basename(os.listdir('/home')[0])` is more reliable across systems (e.g., desktop vs raspberry pi), assuming you are the only user of course.

Comment: @WalkerHaleIV - what are you talking about?!? Yes it is! What isn't available is os.getuid. And pwd, at all.

Comment: On MacOS it is just giving me 'root' even though I am not logged in as root.

Answer (score 111):

Windows:

```
os.environ.get('USERNAME')
```

Linux:

```
os.environ.get('USER')
```

Both:

```
os.environ.get('USER', os.environ.get('USERNAME'))
```

Note that **environment variables can be modified by the user**, so this is a potential security vulnerability. With this method, an attacker can easily fake their username.

Comment: `os.getenv(...)` is deprecated in favour of `os.environ[...]`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be USER instead of USERNAME?

Comment: @MikeGraham [`os.getenv`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.getenv) doesn't seem to be deprecated..?

Comment: Yes, exactly USER vs USERNAME is exactly what is not portable, so  it doesn't provide the correct answer.

Comment: USERNAME is for Windows, 
USER is for Linux

Comment: USER is not present for my test with PythonWin GUI window.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr Exactly, therefore also `USERNAME` is queried in the expression.

Comment: just noted it down for illustrating how "complicated" a specific scenario assignment might turn out.

Comment: The fact that the user can change the environment variables is NOT a security vulnerability.  If doing that can cause a problem, it's indicative of a larger problem with the server-side of your application lacking proper authentication, and adjusting client-side code to obtain the username though some other means will not actually fix the underlying problem.

Answer (score 25):

These might work.  I don't know how they behave when running as a service.  They aren't portable, but that's what `os.name` and `if`statements are for.

```
win32api.GetUserName()

win32api.GetUserNameEx(...)
```

See:
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html

Comment: This answer is at least as useful as the (useless) 25-vote upvoted unix-only answer.

Comment: >"At least as useful" Agreed. Presumably the right answer is a combination of the two.

Comment: If you're stuck on python 2 on Windows, this is the only safe way to do it.
All the other ways can be tricked by running
```SET USERNAME=FAKE```
before your python command

Answer (score 24):

If you are needing this to get user's home dir, below could be considered as portable (win32 and linux at least), part of a standard library.

```
>>> os.path.expanduser('~')
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\johnsmith'
```

Also you could parse such string to get only last path component (ie. user name).

See: [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: Someone's home directory does not always reflect their username.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you set the HOME variable in Windows, this will return it that value.

Answer (score 19):

[psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) provides a portable way that doesn't use environment variables like the `getpass` solution.  It is less prone to security issues, and should probably be the accepted answer as of today.

```
import psutil

def get_username():
    return psutil.Process().username()
```

Under the hood, this combines the `getpwuid` based method for unix and the `GetTokenInformation` method for Windows.

Comment: Is there a function in there to get it without the domain or do I split it on the `/` ?

Comment: split on the "\\" if present, yes, see: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1049

Answer (score 17):

To me using `os` module looks the best for portability: Works best on both Linux and Windows.

```
import os

# Gives user's home directory
userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')          

print "User's home Dir: " + userhome

# Gives username by splitting path based on OS
print "username: " + os.path.split(userhome)[-1]
```

Output:

Windows:

> User's home Dir: C:\Users\myuser
>
> username: myuser

Linux:

> User's home Dir: /root
>
> username: root

No need of installing any modules or extensions.

Comment: This solution is clever, but makes some assumptions that aren't always true.  There is no constraint that requires the username to appear in the homedir path on Linux.  It just happens to be the case most of the time, but a sysadmin can set a user's homedir to whatever they want.

Comment: Setting the HOME variable defeats this.

Answer (score 15):

Combined `pwd` and `getpass` approach, based on other answers:

```
try:
  import pwd
except ImportError:
  import getpass
  pwd = None

def current_user():
  if pwd:
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid()).pw_name
  else:
    return getpass.getuser()
```

Comment: [getpass.getuser()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getuser)
Retrieves non-empty string from these environment variables LOGNAME, USER, LNAME and USERNAME, in order. If none are set, then login name from password database is returned on systems which support pwd module, else raises exception.

[pw_name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pwd.html) is also login name

Comment: I might only use the `pwd` side, but this is the only answer here that gets the name of the _effective_ user ID.

Answer (score 7):

For UNIX, at least, this works...

```
import commands
username = commands.getoutput("echo $(whoami)")
print username
```

**edit:**
I just looked it up and this works on Windows and UNIX:

```
import commands
username = commands.getoutput("whoami")
```

On UNIX it returns your username, but on Windows, it returns your user's group, slash, your username.

--

I.E.

UNIX returns: "username"

Windows returns: "domain/username"

--

It's interesting, but probably not ideal unless you are doing something in the terminal anyway... in which case you would probably be using `os.system` to begin with. For example, a while ago I needed to add my user to a group, so I did (this is in Linux, mind you)

```
import os
os.system("sudo usermod -aG \"group_name\" $(whoami)")
print "You have been added to \"group_name\"! Please log out for this to take effect"
```

I feel like that is easier to read **and** you don't have to import pwd or getpass.

I also feel like having "domain/user" could be helpful in certain applications in Windows.

Comment: WIndows returns `domain/user`  not `group/user`

Comment: The commands module does not work on Windows. It's a UNIX specific module (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html).

It's now deprecated and subprocess is recommended instead.

`user = subprocess.check_output("whoami").replace("\r\n", "")`

Comment: 2 remarks.  commands.whoami did great, even in the context of a service running under a different username. i.e. with   `chpst -u nobody python ./manage.py celerycam --pidfile=/var/run/celerycam/celerycam.pid ` I got **nobody**.  second, `user = subprocess.check_output("whoami").strip()`  is more portable than the replace linefeeds above. `commands` vs `subprocess` seems nitpicky but commands is missing from python 3.

Comment: -1 for using unsafe methods, at the very least you should be using `subprocess`, but spawning a separate process for this is excessive regardless.

Answer (score 7):

Using only standard python libs:

```
from os import environ
from sys import platform

def getUser():
    return environ["USERNAME"] if platform.startswith("win") else environ["USER"]

user = getUser()
```

Works on Windows, Mac or Linux.

Comment: getpass is also a standard lib

Comment: doesnt work for me in win10, python3.7.4. its complaining about 'USER' not being found in envirnment variables I guess. I guess getpass is a better choice anyway.

Comment: The only thing that would cause this is if you run it from a drive other than `C:`. That is the only reason it would use the `USER` key and not `USERNAME`. This is literally just an if/else... All it does is use `USERNAME` if there is a `C:` drive else `USER`

Comment: This is just a hacky solution and will break if your current working directory is on another drive. Your answer doesn't really provide a benefit over the others. There are better ways to check the platform even if you wanted to go that way, but usually it's preferable to use something that's portable from the start.

Comment: @Rob Grant good edit

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked in my case (scroll down to the actual solution).
The problem I'm getting with all solutions is the wrong username when running commands with `sudo`:

- `psutil` soulution:

```sh
$ python3
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.Process().username()
'ubuntu' # OK!

$ sudo su
$ python3
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.Process().username()
'root' # OK!

$ sudo python3
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.Process().username()
'root' # WRONG, should be ubuntu!
```

- `getpass` solution:

```sh
$ python3
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'ubuntu' # OK!

$ sudo su
$ python3
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'root' # OK!

$ sudo python3
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'root' # WRONG, should be ubuntu!
```

- `pwd` + `os.getuid` solution:

```sh
$ python3
>>> import os, pwd
>>> pwd.getpwuid( os.getuid() )[ 0 ]
'ubuntu' # OK!

$ sudo su
$ python3
>>> import os, pwd
>>> pwd.getpwuid( os.getuid() )[ 0 ]
'root' # OK!

$ sudo python3
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'root' # WRONG, should be ubuntu!
```

- `os.getlogin` works a bit different, but still wrong:

```sh
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> os.getlogin()
'ubuntu' # OK!

$ sudo su
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> os.getlogin()
'ubuntu' # WRONG, should be root!


$ sudo python3
>>> import os
>>> os.getlogin()
'ubuntu' # OK!
```

- `os.getenv` gives the same results:

```sh
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('SUDO_USER', os.getenv('USER'))
'ubuntu' # OK!

$ sudo su
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('SUDO_USER', os.getenv('USER'))
'ubuntu' # WRONG, should be root!


$ sudo python3
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('SUDO_USER', os.getenv('USER'))
'ubuntu' # OK!
```

Switching `SUDO_USER` and `USER` gives the wrong result in `sudo python3` case.

### Actual solution (non-portable)

Solution is a bit tricky and rely on the default root home directory location but works for all cases:

```sh
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> 'root' if os.path.expanduser('~') == '/root' else os.getenv('SUDO_USER', os.getenv('USER'))
'ubuntu' # OK!

$ sudo su
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> 'root' if os.path.expanduser('~') == '/root' else os.getenv('SUDO_USER', os.getenv('USER'))
'root' #  OK!

$ sudo python3
>>> import os
>>> 'root' if os.path.expanduser('~') == '/root' else os.getenv('SUDO_USER', os.getenv('USER'))
'ubuntu' # OK!
```

Comment: This is the answer to a very different question

Comment: But grateful for it - deals with the `sudo` issue for that very different question for those looking for the answer to it from a Google search that leads here. Perhaps only a *somewhat* different question.

Comment: sudo escalates so root is effectively the user. if you want to be able to define your own user, I recommend creating a -u/--user flag so you can do something like `sudo ./foo.py -u myUser`, etc

Comment: As the others said, the result you are getting is not wrong. The command *is* running as root for all intents and purposes. This may be useful to someone but it's not an answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the plx module some time ago to get the user name in a portable way on Unix and Windows (among other things):
http://www.decalage.info/en/python/plx

Usage:

```
import plx

username = plx.get_username()
```

(it requires win32 extensions on Windows)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current username on Windows by going through the Windows API, although it's a bit cumbersome to invoke via the ctypes FFI ([GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179) → [OpenProcessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295) → [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671) → [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166)).

I wrote a small module that can do this straight from Python, [getuser.py](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7559409). Usage:

```
import getuser
print(getuser.lookup_username())
```

It works on both Windows and *nix (the latter uses the `pwd` module as described in the other answers).

Answer (score -4):

this works for me:

```
import os
os.cmd("whoami")
print (os.cmd("whoami"))
```

Comment: There is no `os.cmd`. Is this Python's built-in [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)?

Comment: yes the built-in os module. running Python 3.7 running on a Pi4B with RaspberryOS Buster.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, because it's not listed in the [Python 3.7 docs for the `os` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html).

Comment: hhmmm a non-documented feature. normally called a "bug" :-)