# How to determine what user and group a Python script is running as?

Tags: python, unix, permissions

I have a CGI script that is getting an `"IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"` error in the stack trace in the web server's error log.

As part of debugging this problem, I'd like to add a little bit of code to the script to print the user and (especially) group that the script is running as, into the error log (presumably STDERR).

I know I can just print the values to `sys.stderr`, but how do I figure out what user and group the script is running as?

(I'm particularly interested in the group, so the `$USER` environment variable won't help; the CGI script has the setgid bit set so it should be running as group "list" instead of the web server's "www-data" - but I need code to see if that's actually happening.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code:

```
import os
print(os.getegid())
```

Comment: This returns the *group* but not the *user* right? From the docs: `[This returns] the effective group id of the current process. This corresponds to the “set id” bit on the file being executed in the current process.`.

Comment: Yes, it's the id of the group not the user.

Comment: `os.geteuid()` returns the effective *user* id

Answer (score 62):

```
import os
import getpass
print(getpass.getuser())
```

Consider the following script.

```
---- foo.py ----     
import os
import getpass
print("Env thinks the user is [%s]" % (os.getlogin()))
print("Effective user is [%s]" % (getpass.getuser()))
```

Consider running the script.

```
$ python ./foo.py
```

results in

```
Env thinks the user is [jds]
Effective user is [jds]
```

now run

```
$ sudo -u apache python ./foo.py
```

results in

```
Env thinks the user is [jds]
Effective user is [apache]
```

As you can see, you these 2 calls `os.getlogin()` and `getpass.getuser()` are not the same thing.
The underlying principle is how linux/and other unix's  manages the running user.

Consider

```
$ id -u
```

1000

vs the effective id of the running process.

```
$ sudo -u apache id -u
```

33

Note: this is exactly what web servers are doing when they start up. They are creating a sandbox (by forking/divorcing the psudo terminal etc),
and running as another user. For an in-depth account of what is going on here: see the chapter on 'daemon processes' in the [Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment](http://www.apuebook.com/) book.

[Another good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

`os.getgid()` and `os.getuid()` can be useful.  For other environment variables, look into `os.getenv`.  For example, `os.getenv('USER')` on my Mac OS X returns the username. `os.getenv('USERNAME')` would return the username on Windows machines.

Comment: You might take a look at getpass.getuser() as well.

Comment: I concur, getpass.getuser() gets the login name, which is generally what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import os

username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
print("Username       : " + username)
```