# Figure out which user Django code is running under

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu as an ec2 instance on AWS, where I hosted a Django application using Apache2 and mod_wsgi. In my code I am trying to get the username through `os.environ['USERNAME']` statement, which returns a `KeyError: 'USERNAME'`, how can I get the username?

I want that username because I need to set permissions for a sqlite datebase file, since I cann't know the username, therefore cann't set the permissions on that file.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042304/how-to-determine-what-user-and-group-a-python-script-is-running-as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `os.environ["USER"]` it would return your current user from environment variables.

Alternatively you may try following to get current user by using `getpass`

```
import getpass

getpass.getuser() # This would return current user.
```