# running command in background

Tags: python, django

I am using python subprocess module to run some command and store its output in background. The command is deployed on my machine. Now whenever i run the command from shell prompt it works fine. But when I try to run the same command using subprocess module it gives following error

The command to be executed is `vxswadm listswitch all`

```
process = subprocess.Popen('vxswadm listswitch all > tmp.txt &',shell=True)          
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/vxswadm", line 30, in <module>
    l.uname = os.getlogin()
    OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Can anyone help me out to fix this error . Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Tazim

Comment: It could be either the way your handling stdout, or an error occuring in stdout itself. Have you been able to successfully run the command by itself outside of python?

Comment: yes command works properly on shell prompt

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely due to the bash shell terminating immediately after the `&` and sending the SIGHUP singal to all of it's subprocesses (standard shell behavior).

You can use the subprocess module to directly execute the command and can redirect the output to `tmp.txt` yourself by first opening the file and then by passing it's file handle to the `stdout` argument of the Popen call.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with os.getlogin() and subprocessing and python.
See http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/288845/

You need to use something else, such as:

`pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name` (Unix only)

See also the [discussion on a portable way to get the username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `['vxswadm', 'listswitch', 'all', '>', 'tmp.txt','&']` and/or changing shell to `False`.

I think it might be the shell bit, though (if that fixes it).

You may also try adding `stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, though I doubt that will affect it.