# How do I get the username in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a portable way to get the current username in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python)

How can I get the username of the account by which the given script is being executed?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
import getpass
print getpass.getuser()
```

Comment: "os.getlong()" cannot work properly if I switched user on *nix platforms, but the getpass solution works, thank you.

Comment: This ultimately looks at environment variables to determine the username, and hence might be handy for hacky scripts within a semi-trusted environment (e.g. your office) but should not be used for anything public or important. See the 'duplicate' question for some UNIX and Windows API ways of doing this properly.