# Exception while creating a COM object with comtype

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, com, comtypes

In one of my projects we are using comtypes to remote control GUI applications in order to automize testing. In case the tests are called manually everything seems to work smoothly, but in case jenkins is executing the test cases it might happen, that a strange OSError is thrown by

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject

app=createObject("App")
```

The error reading is:

```
OSError: [WinError -2147467238] The server processs could not be started, as the configured identity is wrong. Check your username and password.
```

Does anyone know how it might be possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-error-codes-1) as

```
CO_E_RUNAS_LOGON_FAILURE
0x8000401A
```

Please use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654122/how-to-make-python-get-the-username-in-windows-and-then-implement-it-in-a-script) to check which user is executing the script in your manual and automatized testing and I am quite sure they are different.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. Hopefully, we can gain some insights from your hint.