# How can I write the code to open an app without entering a specific username

Tags: python-3.9

How can I write `os.getlogin` to open an app like zoom using the code given below

`subprocess.Popen('C:\\Users\\srini\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe')`

I first tried this
`subprocess.Popen('C:\\Users\\', os.getlogin, '\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe')`

The code is running but the app is not being opened by python
I had imported **subprocess** and **os**

I tried this code too just to see that if it works
`os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%userprofile%"),"AppData", "Roaming", "Zoom", "bin", "Zoom.exe")`

But it's still the same

Is there any way to open and app without writing the path or a way that makes this task easier?

I want to write this code for almost all apps on my laptop so are there any codes that can help me in the way mentioned in the above question

BTW I am a beginner and I know few codes, so plz help me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track using os.getlogin().  You can also use getlogin.getuser() or os.getenv('username').

Look at [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654122/how-to-make-python-get-the-username-in-windows-and-then-implement-it-in-a-script) to create your path.

```
path = os.path.join("c:\\Users",os.getlogin(), "AppData", "Roaming", "Zoom", "bin", "Zoom.exe")
subprocess.Popen(path)
```

or in one line with f-strings

```
subprocess.Popen(f"c:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe")
```