# How to download multiple worksheets using Smartsheet API?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I want to script the download of 8 sheets using the module [smartsheet-python-sdk](https://pypi.org/project/smartsheet-python-sdk/).

Later I want to automate the download scheduled at a specific time once a week with Windows Task Scheduler.

But I have trouble with the Python script downloading the sheets via API.

This is what I have in a .py file.

```
import os, smartsheet

token=os.environ['SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN']

smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(token)

smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)

smartsheet_client.Reports.get_report_as_excel(
  8729488427892475,
  'C:/Desktop',
  'MyFileName.xlsx'
)
```

Comment: Given your report-id you want to download a single XLS file using the opreation [`get-report-as-excel-csv`](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-report-as-excel-csv). What is not working as expected, any errors you can post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice a couple of issues with the code you've posted.

First, `smartsheet_client.Reports.get_report_as_excel` should be [`smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel`](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet-as-excel-pdf-csv) if you're wanting to retrieve a **sheet** (not a **report**).

Next, try specifying the full path for where **Desktop** actually lives on the file system. i.e., instead of just using the alias `C:\Desktop` -- specify the actual file system path, for example: `c:/users/USERNAME/desktop` (on a Windows machine) where **USERNAME** is the name of the currently logged in user. You can also derive the logged-in user dynamically, see [How to make Python get the username in windows and then implement it in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654122/how-to-make-python-get-the-username-in-windows-and-then-implement-it-in-a-script).

The following code successfully downloads the specified sheet to my Desktop, with the filename **MyFileName.xlsx**. (I'm logged in as `kbrandl` so the path to my Desktop is specified as: `c:/users/kbrandl/desktop`.)

```
sheetId = 3932034054809476

smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel(
    sheetId,
    'c:/users/kbrandl/desktop',
    'MyFileName.xlsx'
)
```

Comment: OMG! That worked! I changed it to: smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel and that did it. (I intentionally left out the "user/" part of the desktop address b/c it had my ID)

Comment: Happy I could help. Can you please mark my answer as "Accepted" (and also 'upvote' the answer, if you want to)? Doing so will make others more likely to benefit from this info in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Great to have some Smartsheet users that know and spot the difference between _report_ and _sheet_ plus have Windows to reproduce it.