# Capture the UserID and send to Slack Channel using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, webhooks, slack

I'm having an issue capturing the userid that will send a message to my Slack Channel and give me a visibility who uses my Python script. The variable name that I use in my Workflow Slack Channel is User and it's data type is Text. The script works fine if I hard code the user but that is not what I want.

I tried below script but it gives me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
import json
import requests

#This will send a slack message to my logs channel

url = "https://hooks.slack.com/workflows/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXX"
data = {'User': <@User>, 'Message': 'used the app!'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

I'm expecting the script will capture the userid whoever uses the script and send message to my Slack Channel. Correct syntax would be nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you're trying to get the value of User from? Through Slack API?

Comment: @Kulasangar actually I have setup Slack API and I'm really not sure how to incorporate it to my python script.

Comment: can you try `<@memberID>` instead of User?

Comment: data = {'User': <@memberID>, 'Message': 'used the app!'}
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Resolved this question by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654122/how-to-make-python-get-the-username-in-windows-and-then-implement-it-in-a-script