# Getting User From Within Python Script

Tags: python

What is a "pythonic" way to determine which user ran a python script from within the script?

For instance, I know that you can run shell commands from within the script to do an

```
echo $USER
```

but is there a more standard python way of determining which user is running the script?

Like a `get_user()` command for a standard library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, the answer is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/2531279

Note: this is available for Windows and Unix

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it depend on what OS you are running the script on? Running shell commands is more common on some flavor of Linux but it could be a windows or Mac machine. Python may have a way of doing that cross platform, i'm not sure.