# WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\%username%\\Desktop'

Tags: python-2.7, path

I want to change my current working directory during the execution of the the script to my Desktop.

I used:

```
import os

os.chdir("C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Desktop")
```

but its showing `ERROR 3`

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\%username%\\Desktop'
```

Comment: Because there isn't a user named %username%

Comment: i want this code to work on multiple machines. I can't hard code my username in the script.. Is there any way to generalise this. above works in cmd so I thought it might work in python too.

Comment: `%username%` is an environment variable. You will have to expand it within the pathname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/198633), it looks like you need this (I'm on a mac, so I can't test this myself):

```
import getpass
import os

os.chdir("C:\Documents and Settings\%s\Desktop" %getpass.getuser())
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this way:

```
import os

os.chdir(os.path.expandvars("C:\Documents and Settings\${username}\Desktop"))
```

This solution is more generic because it would work for any environment variable.