# Shutting down computer from a python script in apache

Tags: python, linux, apache2, raspbian

I have a headless Raspberry Pi which I want to have an easy means for my child to power down.  I tried the following script in the apache web server:

```
import os
sss = os.popen('echo password | sudo -S shutdown -hP now')
print sss.read()
```

But nothing happens.

Then I tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen('echo password | sudo -S shutdown -hP now', shell=True, stdOUT=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print p.stdout.read()
```

Also, nothing was output and no work appears to have been done.

How can I do a shutdown from a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons Apache user cannot run `sudo` command.

Usually this is an almost mandatory rule to save you from attacks but for a Raspberry PI installation you may not have this problem so you can just add Apache user to [sudoers](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo) (or, better, uso [visudo](http://www.sudo.ws/visudo.man.html) to edit that file).

Something else? Yes you may simply add shutdown permissions to Apache user, follow [this tutorial](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_allow_non-super_users_to_shutdown_computer_in_Linux). In short you have to change `/etc/sudoers` with:

```
%groupName ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I find out the account running Apache?

Comment: @OldGeezer you can call [getuser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python) from phyton but probably it's running on default account (_www-data_ or _apache_)