# get the logged in RDP user in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rdp

I don't know much about RDP, so this question may not make sense but:

What is the correct way to detect, in Python, which user is currently logged into the server through RDP?

Would the answer to this question: [Is there a portable way to get the current username in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python) work as well on a remoted log in?

Comment: What RDP server do you mean? The one, on which you are going to run the python code, or some remote one?

Comment: the code will run on the server which is being RDPed into (if that makes sense...)

Comment: In that case you shall try the solution described in the link you have provided.