# Get parent user after sudo with Python

Tags: python, unix

I would like to get the *parent* user after a `sudo` command in Python
For example, from the shell I can do:

```
# Shows root; *undesired* output
$ sudo whoami
root

# Shows parent user sjcipher, desired output
$ sudo who am i
sjcipher
```

How do I do this in Python without using an external program?

Comment: without calling external command please read my question.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2899055/2073595

Comment: that is different, please check the difference of whoami and who am i

Comment: whats up with `who am i` thats just the command `who`

Comment: its different please check the above output

Comment: im confused about what you want exactly ... I dont want to see you just copy and paste some output from a command you dont want to use... I would like to see you explain what information you would like to display

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's just an equivalent of `who -m`: "If  ARG1  ARG2  given, -m presumed: 'am i' or 'mom likes' are usual."

Comment: @JoranBeasley i am trying to figure out the username before switch user, like if a user run a script with sudo, but i want to logged his original username.

Comment: @dano thanks :) ... shows my newbness with *nix

Comment: `os.getlogin()` will work if there's a controlling terminal.

Comment: @dano awesome os.getlogin() did the job :)

Comment: why this question is duplicate ???

Comment: @sjcipher: It's not, really. But you original question was phrased in such a way that it very much *looked* like a duplicate. Only in your comments to some proposed answers did it become clear that it wasn't... Anyhow, I rephrased your question, and nominated it to be re-openend.

Comment: Ok thank you so much Carpetsmonker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`who am i` gets it's information from [`utmp(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp);
with Python you can access with information with [pyutmp](http://software.clapper.org/pyutmp/);

Here's an example, adapted from the `pyutmp` homepage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from pyutmp import UtmpFile
import time, os

mytty = os.ttyname(os.open("/dev/stdin", os.O_RDONLY))

for utmp in UtmpFile():
    if utmp.ut_user_process and utmp.ut_line == mytty:
        print '%s logged in at %s on tty %s' % (utmp.ut_user, time.ctime(utmp.ut_time), utmp.ut_line)


$ ./test.py
martin logged in at Tue Jul  1 21:38:35 2014 on tty /dev/pts/5

$ sudo ./test.py
martin logged in at Tue Jul  1 21:38:35 2014 on tty /dev/pts/5
```

Drawbacks: this is a C module (ie. it requires compiling), and only works with Python 2 (not 3).

Perhaps a better alternative is using of the environment variables that `sudo` offers? For example:

```
[~]% sudo env | grep 1001
SUDO_UID=1001
SUDO_GID=1001

[~]% sudo env | grep martin
SUDO_USER=martin
```

So using something like `os.environ['SUDO_USER']` *may* be better, depending on what you're exactly trying to do.

Comment: ah this is the easiest os.environ['SUDO_USER'], thats perfectly make sense.

Answer (score 8):

SUDO_USER environmental variable should be available in most cases:

```
import os

if os.environ.has_key('SUDO_USER'):
    print os.environ['SUDO_USER']
else:
    print os.environ['USER']
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the setup you could use the environment variables that have been set. Note, that this may not work in all cases but may in yours. Should return the original user before su.

```
import os
print os.environ["USER"]
```

Comment: this will give the current user not the one before switch user.

Comment: Worked fine for me after switch user. What OS are you targeting if I may ask?

Comment: i am running on RHEL 6.3

Comment: Odd, I tested it on RHEL 5.5 and it worked. Oh well, seems like you found an answer with the os module anyway.

Comment: if i do `sudo python` and go to interactive shell and did it gave me 'root' but i am expecting to see the original user who run sudo. btw thank you i learnt something.

Comment: That's why. I was su'ing to root and then running python. Explains things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that will do it.

```
user = os.environ['SUDO_USER'] if 'SUDO_USER' in os.environ else os.environ['USER']
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `os.getlogin()` or `os.getenv('SUDO_USER')` look like good choices.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo python3.6
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 11 2017, 18:17:37)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getlogin()
'vagrant'
>>> os.getenv('SUDO_USER')
'vagrant'
>>> os.getenv('USER')
'root'
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'root'
```

Answer (score -1):

as referenced [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/842622), you can use getpass module

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'kostya'
```

Comment: this doest give the original user before sudo or switch user. i am trying to figure out the first user.

Comment: i think you have to make a **bold** note about this. everyone giving answers like me :)