# How to access Bash environment variable in Python using subprocess?

Tags: python, bash, variables, subprocess

I can determine the width of the terminal in Python with a `subprocess-handled` query such as the following:

```
int(subprocess.Popen(['tput', 'cols'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip('\n'))
```

How could I determine the Bash user name in a similar way? So, how could I see the value of `${USER}` in Python using subprocess?

Comment: Why do you want to use `subprocess`? The python process itself has access to the environment.

Comment: You can use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) for this. e.g. `print(os.environ['USER'])`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Part of the motivation is wanting to understand how to use Bash variables in ```subprocess``` methods. I am not sure how to do this. Accessing the environment variable ${USER} is a simple example.

Comment: The thing is, calling Python subprocess with a bash-style variable name does not do any variable expansion, globbing, etc.     There is no shell between Python subprocessing, and the argv/argc of the program you are invoking.

Comment: unrelated: there is [`shutil.get_terminal_size()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size) in Python 3.3+, to get width/height of the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wooble and dano say, don't use subprocess for this. Use `os.getenv("USER")` or `os.environ["USER"]`.

If you really want to use `subprocess` then `Popen(['bash', '-c', 'echo "$USER"'], ...)` seems to work as does `Popen("echo $USER", shell=True)` though neither of those is particularly pleasant (though to use environment variables on the command line being executed the shell must be involved so you can't really avoid it).

Edit: My previous subprocess suggestion did not seem to work correctly. I believe my original test was flawed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions on using the ```getenv``` and ```environ``` methods of the module ```os```. This works well. Part of the motivation in wanting to use the module ```subprocess``` is wanting to understand how to use Bash variables in ```subprocess``` methods. I have tried your ```subprocess.Popen(['echo', '${USER}'])``` suggestion but am presented with '${USER}' as a response rather than the actual environment variable value in both Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.0. Do you know how to access the actual value?

Comment: Ah, great. Your edits have made that work. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @d3pd: A [portable way to find out the current username in Python is `getpass.getuser()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/842059/4279).

Comment: @Etan Reisner: *do not* use a list argument and `shell=True` together. Always pass a string if you use `shell=True` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Would you care to enlighten me as to why? (I am by no means a python person.)

Comment: That's stupid behaviour. Encouraging people to need to format command line arguments themselves for complicated commands is backwards. Expecting individual arguments (which can then be quoted sanely) is much better. But <shrug> there are many reasons I don't do python already. Fixed post to remove the (useless anyway) list brackets.

Comment: @EtanReisner: how do you suggest to split `"a |& b"` shell command into a list? Could name a language that has a builtin shell parser for all platforms that Python supports? Note: the default is `shell=False` i.e., a shell is *not* used  and the command is specified as a sequence of program arguments.

Comment: I didn't suggest that requiring list splitting is a good idea either. I said suggesting that in the default cases people ensure that they get shell quoting correct is a bad decision. Someone who knows enough to know that they want to use a shell and use `|&` in the pipeline is **significantly** more likely to be able to get shell quoting correct than is the average person trying to run a random shell command off user input.