# Replicate os.system functionality with subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, environment-variables, os.system

In my program I want to let the user either run a shell command or execute a binary file. No matter how much I read about `subprocess.Popen` I can't figure out a way to replicate the `os.system()` functionality.

I simply want to `echo $USER` but nothing seems to work.

Turning `shell=True`..

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo', '$USER'], shell=True,\
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
>>> ('\n', '')
```

Passing current environment vars..

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo', '$USER'], shell=True,\
                     env=os.environ\
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
>>> ('\n', '')
```

So what's the proper way to run a shell command?

------- Edit: requirements ---------

Some people posted answers but maybe I should be more specific. I want to keep both **stdout**, **stderr** and return **value stored** somewhere. All answers seem to give either the one or the other.

Comment: Why don't you just use `os.environ['USER']`?

Comment: or even better, `import getpass` and `getpass.getuser()` for cross-os compatibility.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I don't know what commands the user will run so it's easier to just pass all the environments..

Comment: related: [subprocess.call() arguments ignored when using shell=True w/ list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26417658/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to massiou direction I figured out the answer. The culprit is that when using `shell=True` you should pass the whole command as a **single string**!

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo $USER'], shell=True, \
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
>>> ('manos\n', '')
```

The reason is that the first argument in the list will be the one executed as a shell script. The rest arguments are for the shell program itself.

Answer (score 1):

use `call` method

```
subprocess.call('echo $USER',shell=True)
```

Altarnetivly:

```
var = subprocess.check_output('echo $USER',shell=True) # .rstrip('\n')
print var
```

Also with `subprocess.Popen()`

```
process = subprocess.Popen("echo $USER",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.communicate()[0],
```

Comment: That seems to work but I can't seem to save the output in a variable then..

Comment: @Pithikos then go with `check_output`

Comment: thanks, that works. Then though I get no return code. That's why I started with using Popen.. I would prefer to keep all stderr, stdout, return code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do something like:

```
subprocess.call('echo $USER', shell=True)
```

Also, take a look at [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module)