# How to restrict permission to run script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to restrict ability to run my Python 3 script to certain host and users on Linux. Is there any Python 3.x build in function or library which would allow me to do this relatively easy please?

Comment: You want to restrict your scripts execution permissions from within the script itself? For that it would have to be executed first.

Comment: Are you need to restrict only a given script or running Python scripts at all?

Comment: Correct, once script checks user and host name it will either continue to run or stop and exit.

Comment: You have the `os` module, e.g.: [`os.getlogin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.getlogin) and [`os.getgrouplist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.getgrouplist) - also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python)

Comment: @UnholySheep - many thanks that's also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way of doing that but below is my first attempt.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import getpass
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
username = getpass.getuser()
allowedusers = 'user1'
allowedhosts = 'host1'

if hostname in allowedhosts:
    print('hostname allowed')
    if username in allowedusers:
        print('user allowed')

    else:
        print('username not allowed')
        exit()
else:
   print('hostname not allowed')
   exit()

print('script will continue to run as hostname and user are allowed')
```

Comment: Be aware of the fact that acording to docs https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/getpass.html getpass just checks some env variables, so if user runs a script as `LOGNAME='not-really-me' python script.py` then `getuser()` will return `not-really-me`. I strongly recommend doing such checks on the OS level.

Comment: @pax0r I agree, however this is only sort of exercise rather than production with expectations to be super secure. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: even if so, still someone else may read this, so it is worth noticing ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a Python answer, but a Linux one - you may add all users who can run a script to some group:

```
groupadd allowed-users 
usermod -a -G allowed-users some-user
```

Then change group of the script and restrict read access to it only for group (if user can't read a script it can't run it).

```
chown allowed-users script.py
chmod 640 script.py
```