# How do I add variables to a directory in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hello there I have this code:

```
login=os.getlogin()
if not os.path.exist("C:\Users\login\Documents")
```

As you can see I have a login variable that gets the user of the computer but I am struggling to use it in the ''if not os.path.exist'' statement, The output I want is  for python to get the username of the user and use it in a directory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting:

```
if not os.path.exists("C:\Users\{0}\Documents".format(login)):
```

Or you can build up the string by yourself:

```
if not os.path.exists("C:\Users\\" + login + "\Documents"):
```

or if by using join:

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join("C:/", "Users", login, "Documents"):
```

As already indicated by comments, you should also have a look on
this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python). This shows you how to properly get the login
name.

Comment: Note that `os.path.join` is the safest way to generate portable paths.

Comment: Note there is a mistake in the second example- the second \ escapes the closing `"`.

Comment: You can also use f-strings, and the old % syntax instead of `.format()` as well.

Comment: @DillonDavis exactly the kind of mistake `os.path.join` is useful to prevent