# Create A File On Anyones Desktop Using Python

Tags: python, file, desktop

I am looking to create a log file on a users desktop, but since I do not know the username of the person using the computer I cant give my program the directory of where to place the file.

This is what works on PC since my username is mikur.

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\Mihkel\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt", 'a')
```

I have tried using

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt", 'a')
```

but that gives me a no permissions error. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/7698247 have a look

Answer (score 1):

Try

`os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")`

Comment: do I use this as the path/directory?

Comment: file = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/KeyLog.txt"), 'a')

Comment: returns this error: NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Comment: you need to import os at the top of your source file.

Comment: How do I access the file later, I need to send it back to me using MIME. It needs the directory and filename. what would go here: `filename='?????'`

Comment: Could you rephase the question? I fear we are going in circles...  
filename = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/KeyLog.txt")  
or, perhaps you need...  
filename = "KeyLog.txt"  
directory = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/")  
full_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

Comment: I figured it out myself, I used: filename=fullpath=os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Log.txt")) Thanks for the help though!