# How can I get the user's username?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-accounts

I know that I can do `getpass.getuser()` but that shows the user's name, not their account logon username and I want their account logon username

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python)? I feel you want exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

**For Unix**

```py
import os
import pwd

pwd.getpwduid(os.getuid())[0]
```

**For Windows**

```py
import os

os.getlogin()
```

Comment: For some reason it says ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'```. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Because you're probably using windows. I updated my answer with option for windows too.If you are not on windows - try ```pip install pwd``` But I think pwd should be default module...

Answer (score 0):

No permission to edit.
should be pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]