# Get the output of $USER in mac terminal in python

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I try to get the username in a variable on mac OS.
In mac terminal the code is:

```
 $USER
```

I tried to do this in python with

```
import os
os.system('$USER')
```

The output of these lines give me a number.
Any tips for a solution to get the name for mac/python

Comment: Something like `os.getenv('USER')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a portable way to get the current username in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python)

Comment: @Maurice the ‘duplicate’ is about win, but they look alike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USER is an environment variable. To access it use:

```
import os
os.environ['USER']
```