# How to get the username that appears on the cmd?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I need to know how I can get the username that appears on the `cmd` with python, for example in this path:

```
C:\Users\john\Desktop\chrome.exe
```

I want to get the name John in this way, how can I do this with python?

```
C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\chrome.exe
```

How can I get the name with python?

Comment: Do you really want to analyze the command line, or do you want to know who actually ran the program? When `chrome.exe` is in `C:\Program Files` instead of a user's directory, analyzing the path won't help at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? It is how to get the username of the currently logged in user with a Python package (not standard lib): https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/9190640

Comment: From the same thread, supposedly more secure and dependable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65224170/9190640

Comment: @ShadowRanger Like this? I'm trying to figure out the username to run the program that will be in the desktop area, if I have the username I'll be able to believe me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the username, you can use `str.split`:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\chrome.exe"

user_name = path.split("Users\\")[1]
user_name = user_name.split("\\")[0]
print(user_name)
```

Comment: I think the question is how to get the currently logged in user, not how to clean a string.

Comment: Like I said... the username may be different, I don't know what it is for example, I want to be able to find out what the username appears on the cmd

Comment: @Dkns I have updated my solution to get the username, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pass the command line value to a variable, and then you can do this:

```
s = 'C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\chrome.exe'
l = s.split('\\')
l[2].capitalize()
```

> 'John'

Comment: Like I said... the username may be different, I don't know what it is for example, I want to be able to find out what the username appears on the cmd

Comment: On Linux systems you can read files /home/user/.bash_history for all users in your system, which stores all the commands entered by the user in the terminal. As soon as a new record appears there, then the user entered it in the terminal. Home directories are readable on many systems (for example, Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You can automatize a little bit with the os library

```
import os

# get current directory
path = os.getcwd()

# split path into list
path_spit = path.split('\\')

# get index of Users word in the list
idx = path_split.index('Users')

# get user name
user = path_spit[ idx+1 ]
```

Comment: Can you enter the example output please?

Comment: Because assuming I open the cmd in the directory C:\WINDOWS\system32 its code still working?  I want to get the username regardless of the directory I am in