# Relative paths in config.yaml for Snakefile

Tags: python, linux, yaml, snakemake, intake

How can I use relative paths in my configuration file so that users do not need to change `USER` in the paths for output directories?

I have this:

### config.yml

```yaml
proj_name: H1N1_rhesus
contact:
  email: user.edu
  person: user
01-preprocess: /home/user/2022-h1n1/01-preprocess/
02-salmon: /home/user/2022-h1n1/02-salmon/
raw-data: /tmp/H1N1_rhesus/
reference: /tmp/
```

### Snakefile

```py
#----SET VARIABLES----#
PROJ = config["proj_name"]
INPUTDIR = config["raw-data"]
PREPROCESS = config["01-preprocess"]
SALMON = config["02-salmon"]
REFERENCE = config["reference"
```

But would like to do something like this:

```yaml
proj_name: H1N1_rhesus
contact:
  email: user.edu
  person: user
01-preprocess: /home/$(USER)/2022-h1n1/01-preprocess/
02-salmon: /home/$(USER)/2022-h1n1/02-salmon/
raw-data: /tmp/H1N1_rhesus/
reference: /tmp/
```

Or this:

```yaml
proj_name: H1N1_rhesus
contact:
  email: user.edu
  person: user
01-preprocess: /home/$(PWD)/01-preprocess/
02-salmon: /home/$(PWD)/02-salmon/
raw-data: /tmp/H1N1_rhesus/
reference: /tmp/
```

But none of the methods I tried worked.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to add variable like this in yaml file, but you can try define another variable in config.yaml to specify home directory, then concatenate it to the relative path later in Snakefile

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`intake`](https://intake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/catalog.html#yaml-format) for defining catalogues of data. This allows references to environmental variables, for example:

```yaml
sources:
  01-preprocess:
    args:
      url: "/home/{{env(USER)}}/2022-h1n1/01-preprocess/"
```

Inside `Snakefile`, you would have:

```py
import intake
cat = intake.open_catalog('config.yml')
data = cat['01-preprocess'].urlpath
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use f-string formatting (inside Snakefile). So the `.yaml` could contain:

```yaml
proj_name: H1N1_rhesus
paths:
   01-preprocess: /home/{user}/2022-h1n1/01-preprocess/
   02-salmon: /home/{user}/2022-h1n1/02-salmon/
   raw-data: /tmp/H1N1_rhesus/
   reference: /tmp/
```

And inside `Snakefile` you would have:

```py
config: 'config.yaml'

# to identify the user, see comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/10693596
import getpass

paths = {k: v.format(user=getpass.getuser()) for k,v in config['paths'].items()}
```

The `paths` object is a dictionary with the formatted paths.

Comment: I get the following error when I try this method: `KeyError in line 17 of /home/user/2022-h1n1/Snakefile:
'01-preprocess'
  File "/home/user/2022-h1n1/Snakefile", line 17, in <module>`. I suspect it is because I call the configuration variable in the Snakefile. I updated the question above to include that part of the Snakefile.