# Handle environmental variables in config options

Tags: python, configuration, yaml, snakemake, intake

I have snakemake command line with configuration options like this:

```
snakemake --config \
    f1=$PWD/file1.txt \
    f2=$PWD/file2.txt \
    f3=/path/to/file3.txt \
    ...more key-value pairs \
    --directory /path/to/output/dir
```

`file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are expected to be in the same directory as the snakefile, `file3.txt` is somewhere else. I need the paths to files to be absolute, hence the `$PWD` variable, so Snakemake can find the files after moving to `/path/to/output/dir`.

Because I start having several configuration options, I would like to move all the `--config` items to a separate yaml configuration file. The problem is: How do I transfer the variable `$PWD` to a configuration file?

I could have a dummy string in the yaml file indicating that that string is to be replaced by the directory where the Snakefile is (e.g. `f1: <replace me>/file1.txt`) but I feel it's awkward. Any better ideas? It may be that I should rethink how the files `fileX.txt` are passed to snakemake...

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an external module, [`intake`](https://intake.readthedocs.io/), to handle the environmental variable integration. There is a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779215/10693596), but a more specific example for this question is as follow.

A `yaml` file which follows the syntax expected by `intake`, a field called `sources` that contains a list of nested entries that specify at the very least a (possibly local) url at which the file can be access:

```yaml
# config.yml
sources:
  file1:
    args:
      url: "{{env(PWD)}}/file1.txt"
  file2:
    args:
      url: "{{env(PWD)}}/file2.txt"
```

Inside the `Snakefile`, the relevant code would be:

```py
import intake
cat = intake.open_catalog('config.yml')
f1 = cat['file1'].urlpath
f2 = cat['file2'].urlpath
```

Note that for less verbose `yaml` files, `intake` provides syntax for parameterization, see the docs or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69913866/10693596).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the directory the Snakefile lives in with `workflow.basedir` - you might be able to get away with specifying the relative path in the config file and then defining the absolute path in your Snakefile e.g. as

```py
file1 = pathlib.Path(workflow.basedir) / config["f1"]
file2 = pathlib.Path(workflow.basedir) / config["f2"]
```