# This account is not available: Unable to switch user in python alpine docker container

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I have a simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set arguments
ARG USERNAME=jpg
ARG USER_DIR=/home/$USERNAME
ARG WORK_DIR=$USER_DIR/app

# Creating a non-root user
RUN adduser -S $USERNAME

# Switching the user
USER $USERNAME

# Create a new directory to keep the project files
RUN mkdir $WORK_DIR

# Copy local contents into container
COPY ./ $WORK_DIR

# Setting newly created directory as PWD
WORKDIR $WORK_DIR

# Adding user's bin path to `PATH` variable
ENV PATH "$PATH:$USER_DIR/.local/bin"

# Installing pip packages
RUN pip install pip -U
```

I built the image using following command

```
docker build . -t test-img:latest
```

After the successfull image build, run the image using

```
docker run -i -t test-img:latest python
```

This gave me an interactive shell, as expected. Also, I tried to pull the user info using [`getuser(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/842096/8283848) function as well

```
Python 3.10.10 (main, Mar 14 2023, 03:01:12) [GCC 12.2.1 20220924] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass.getuser()
'jpg'
>>>
```

Then, I moved to another terminal and ***logged in to the same container as `root` user***. After logged-in, tried to switch the user to `jpg` (which is defined within the `Dockerfile`)

```
$ docker exec -it -u root f6dc515bca29 sh                                                                                                                                                          
/home/jpg/app # su - jpg
This account is not available
/home/jpg/app # su - "jpg"
This account is not available
/home/jpg/app # su -l "jpg"
This account is not available
/home/jpg/app # su -l jpg
This account is not available
/home/jpg/app #
```

---

#### Question

How can I switch the user to `jpg` (or any non-root user) in an alpine-based container from `root`?

**Note**: It is mandatory to log in as root (`-u root`) in an `exec` session because this is to simulate a situation of AWS Fargate containers.

Comment: I can easily repro in a base `alpine` container. If I remove the `-S` option to `adduser` the account is available. Do you have a particular reason to want to create a system user? Do you actually need to run an interactive shell as this user?

Comment: Start a new `docker exec` shell with the `-u username` you need.  Don't bother trying to use `su` or `sudo` in a debugging shell like this.  Also remember that anything you do in this shell will be lost as soon as the container exits; I wouldn't invest a lot of time in `exec`-based workflows.

Comment: (The username and filesystem paths are local to the image, and I wouldn't bother passing them as `ARG`s.  If you run `WORKDIR` first, it will create the directory, and you can `COPY files ./` without repeating the path.  Don't forget to set a `CMD` that actually runs your program.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your input. But, It is mandatory to log in as root (`-u root`) in an `exec` session because this is to simulate a situation of AWS Fargate containers.

Comment: @tripleee You're right. Removing the `-S` flag fixed the issue. Do you know what could go wrong with the `-S` flag? If you write that as an answer, I'd more happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the `This account is not available` message because running `adduser -S` explicitly sets the shell for the account to `/sbin/nologin` (because you've asked for a system account with `-S`, the assumption is you don't expect interactive logins for this user).

You can explicitly set the shell for the named user:

```
/ # adduser -S -s /bin/sh jpg
/ # su - jpg
710ed667ddb2:~$ whoami
jpg
```

...or, as @tripleee suggests, just drop the `-S` from your `adduser` invocation and create a normal user; in this case, the shell will default to `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use su's `-s` parameter to indicate which shell you want to use. A working example:

```
/ # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),11(floppy),20(dialout),26(tape),27(video)
/ # su mysql
This account is not available
/ # su -s /bin/ash mysql
/ $ id
uid=100(mysql) gid=101(mysql) groups=101(mysql),101(mysql)
```

In my alpine container user *mysql* has `/sbin/nologin` shell. By using `-s` argument to su, I switch to *mysql* user, but use `/bin/ash` shell.