# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'geteuid'

Tags: python, windows, detectron

when I run the code on Win11

```py
# PyTorch still may leave orphan processes in multi-gpu training.
# Therefore we use a deterministic way to obtain port,
# so that users are aware of orphan processes by seeing the port occupied.
    
port = 2 ** 15 + 2 ** 14 + hash(os.getuid()) % 2 ** 14
parser.add_argument(
        "--dist-url", default="tcp://127.0.0.1:{}".format(port)
    )
```

it raise error as follow

```
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'geteuid'
```

I have found an answer on github like this

```
geteuid() is only available on unix like systems. This explains why it doesn't work on Windows.
```

so I want to konw how to replace the **os.getuid()** with others on Win11,or how can I get the **"--dist-url"**?

Comment: Do any of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842059/is-there-a-portable-way-to-get-the-current-username-in-python) solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve this problems on win11

```py
if os.name=='nt':
        port = 2 ** 15 + 2 ** 14 + hash(getpass.getuser()) % 2 ** 14
```

we can use **getpass.getuser()** on Windows.

Comment: `import getpass`