# How to Open a file in python from documents

Tags: file, python-3.x, any

Hi I already know how to open a file in python 3 but is there a way of opening a file in C:\Users\user\Documents (user is the user of the logged in computer). So I want to open a text file in any users Documents named something e.g. test.txt This file maybe on 3 computers and I want to open the file with the same name in many logons.

This is how you would normally open a file in python:

```
file = open("C:\Users\Rohit\Documents\text.txt", "r+")
file.close()
```

So is there a way to replace 'Rohit' with the user logged on e.g. Robert, Adam, Lewis, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Windows, but according to [os.path's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) you should be able to do something like this:

`file = open(expanduser("~\Documents\text.txt"), "r+")`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `os` to get the username.

```
import os
os.environ.get("USERNAME")
```

or

```
os.getlogin()
```

[How to Retrieve name of current Windows User (AD or local) using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117014/how-to-retrieve-name-of-current-windows-user-ad-or-local-using-python)

Or, as described by R. Mitchum, you can bypass getting the user name explicitly

```
os.path.expanduser("~\Documents\\text.txt")
```

will get you the filepath to `text.txt` for the current user:

```
C:\\Users\\CURRENTUSER\\Documents\\text.txt
```